# query_string query doesn't take word order into consideration

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following documents:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "ello worl" }
{ _id: 2, name: "world hello" }
{ _id: 3, name: "hello world" }
```

When I execute the following query:

```
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "​*ello* *worl*"
    }
  }
}
```

Documents are ordered in the same order as above, but I was expecting them to be in `1) 3) 2)` order.

My question is: **Why doesn't the third document have higher score than the second one?**

P.S. Using wildcards is mandatory.

Comment: Have a look at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/query-string-with-wildcard-does-not-calculate-score/5588/3

Comment: The person having a similar problem complained it doesn't help at all, and quite frankly I have no idea what that linked issue was about :) Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The question describes the same problem which you are facing. The score of all documents returned is same b'coz you are using wildcards

Comment: Ok, so this means that it is impossible to sort documents by relevance using wildcards. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it is impossible to sort documents by relevance with wildcards out of the box in elasticsearch. So the workaround that I found is to do a boolean query with multiple `should` leaf queries each of which performs a wildcard search in itself with different boosts.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { query_string: { query: "ello worl", boost: 4 } },
        { query_string: { query: "ello* worl*", boost: 3, analyze_wildcard: true } },
        { query_string: { query: "*ello *worl", boost: 2, analyze_wildcard: true } },
        { query_string: { query: "*ello* *worl*", analyze_wildcard: true } } 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```